# Windows 10 taskbar/start menu problems Version: 10.0.10586 Build 10586

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu, reinstall

I always had this problem and I thought clean reinstall would fix it, but that isn't the case. I reinstalled windows 10 x64 yesterday and today I'm already facing the same issue.This doesn't always happen, just sometimes when I boot up:

[image]

Also, sometimes when I don't use the computer and it goes to sleep, when I log back to the desktop everything is in place on the taskbar, but start menu, volume, action center etc. does not open. Only restarting pc helps.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this happen while in Safe Mode?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tested it, cause it's hard to test. Sometimes it does not happen for two days straight, sometimes it happens twice a day

Comment: I can't even begin to help till I know if it happens in Safe Mode or not.

Comment: @Ramhound how can i test that? Just boot it in safe mode for couple of days?